# Counterexample: weak convergence doesn't imply $L^1-$convergence

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I'm not sure my question is of research level, but I cannot find the answer in the existing reference. Let $\mu_n$ be a sequence of probability measures on $\mathbb R$ satisfying

$$\int_{\mathbb R}xd\mu_n~=~0,~~~ \int_{\mathbb R}x^+d\mu_n~=~C \mbox{ for all } n\ge 1.$$

Assume further $\mu_n$ converges weakly to some $\mu$. Could some one may provide an example such that

$$\int_{\mathbb R}xd\mu_n~\neq~0 \mbox{ or } \int_{\mathbb R}x^+d\mu_n~\neq~C?$$

Clearly, if $\mu_n$s are not required to be probability measures, there are several examples. But as for probability measures, I cannot find such an example. Many thx!

Comment: $\mu$ instead of $\mu_n$ in the 2nd display?

Answer (score 4):

If, for $n>2$, $\mu_n$ puts masses $n^{-1},n^{-1}, 1-2n^{-1}$ at $2n, -n, -\frac{n}{n-2}$ respectively (so that $\mu$ puts the unit mass at $-1$), doesn't it work?